# Arrow bouncing to the bottom right corner in CSS

Tags: css, animation, transform

I need an arrow to slightly move (bounce) to the bottom right corner on hover, using CSS. I've used the code below and I like what it does however this only moves the arrow left/right. How do I amend it so that it moves slightly to the bottom as well? I've tried using 'translateY' but couldn't workout the exact pixel amount for the animation to be smooth.

[image]

I've tried using 'bounce' but actually 'swing' seems to look better.
What I'm looking for is the kind on animation of this page:

http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/   (called 'Wobble to Bottom Right')

```
.arrow:hover{

-webkit-animation: swing 1s ease;
animation: swing 1s ease;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-iteration-count: 1;

}

@-webkit-keyframes swing
{
    15%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(5px);
        transform: translateX(5px);
    }
    30%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-5px);
       transform: translateX(-5px);
    } 
    50%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(3px);
        transform: translateX(3px);
    }
    65%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px);
        transform: translateX(-3px);
    }
    80%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(2px);
        transform: translateX(2px);
    }
    100%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
@keyframes swing
{
    15%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(5px);
        transform: translateX(5px);
    }
    30%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-5px);
        transform: translateX(-5px);
    }
    50%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(3px);
        transform: translateX(3px);
    }
    65%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px);
        transform: translateX(-3px);
    }
    80%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(2px);
        transform: translateX(2px);
    }
    100%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a gif or an image with the end animation. Also adding a full example would help.

Comment: Use `translate(x,y)` instead of `translateX(x)` if you want 2d transformation

Comment: I would prefer to use CSS rather than gif. I've added an image to show the kind of animation I'm after. Thanks

Comment: @fen1x Yes, that's probably what I need to use. But not sure what the values (x,y) should be for a smooth animation to bottom right corner and back up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use translate(x,y) instead of translateX(x) for 2d transformation as @fen1x mentioned in the comment above

Try this:

```
@keyframes hvr-wobble-to-bottom-right {

16.65% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(8px, 8px);
    transform: translate(8px, 8px);
}

33.3% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-6px, -6px);
    transform: translate(-6px, -6px);
}

49.95% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(4px, 4px);
    transform: translate(4px, 4px);
}

66.6% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
    transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
}

83.25% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1px, 1px);
    transform: translate(1px, 1px);
}

100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Works exactly as needed. Thank you